# Is there a way to send a hint to someone who suggest lots of edits?

Tags: discussion, review, messaging

As you can see from my rep I'm rather new to the "review suggested edits" privilege, so I'm searching for some advice.

Currently there are a lot of edit suggestions from one user, which mainly consist of converting `keys` to <kbd>keys</kbd>. Although I personally do not like this `<kdb>` style, I approved most of the edits I reviewed because `<kdb>` is implemented for some reason (i.e. the community likes it).

Now, I struggled over some edits like [here](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/115948) where `CTRL+LARROW` gets edited to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>. It [seems](https://superuser.com/users/128997/linger?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) that @Linger will edit some more posts in the future, so I think it would be a good hint for him/her, that instead of `<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>` one can use `<kbd>&larr;</kbd>` etc. to draw a ,,real'' arrow.

But I see no possibility to send directly a message during the review process. (Although @slhck comments [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5096/195224) that ,,users should actually get a fair amount of feedback on their edits when they're below 2k''.)

Does this mean, I should *reject* those edits, writing the possible improvement as the reason why I rejected, *improve* this myself (this doubles the work) or just *accept* the edit (because most people won't care if there is a ← pictogram or not)?

Comment: Sounds *too minor*. Both the user's edits (if that's all there is to them) and your improvement. This is just personal preference.

Comment: There [still is no real notification system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624) for rejected edits, which would come in useful in such situations. [Shog9's suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/159624) would also make sense here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `<kbd>` is the only thing a user is adding to a post, reject. Adding keyboard markup does not improve the post in any way—okay, it's nice to look at, but you can safely assume that a reader will know that Ctrl-K refers to an actual keyboard shortcut. And if it's "Left Arrow" or ← doesn't matter either. In fact, we've had some users confused over what ⇥ meant (the Tab character often seen in OS X).

On the other hand, if the edit fixes other things, like spelling and grammar, and adds `<kbd>` markup as icing on the cake, then it's okay to approve.

When a user seems to be targeting posts with keyboard shortcuts specifically, they should probably [focus on tags that need more attention](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-may-2013) instead.

As there is no specific message you can send a user, you only have a few limited options:

- Reject the edit if it is too minor. Leave a custom message. If the user has too many rejected edits, they will not be able to edit posts for a few days (7 IIRC).
- Find a post edited by the user, and @-ping them in a comment. It'll notify them. Just ask them nicely to slow down, or invite them to chat.
- Flag one of the posts they edited.
- Come to Meta.

In that case, I pinged the user in chat to stop by and weigh in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I totally agree that the pictograms are sometimes hard to dechipher (and even are ambiguous; &larr; can also mean backspace), but <kbd>Left Arrow</kdb> deemed to me as a wild mixture. In future I try to focus more on the content than on such (minor) formatting issues.

Comment: Might want to contact [this guy](http://superuser.com/users/229729/idavid). All I see from him are kbd tag edits, and I'm extremely surprised at how a 10k and even a 100k user seem to be blindly approving them all.